# Как определить, что блок данных из файла является последним

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, filestream

Задача: есть бинарный файл, размер которого кратен 16-ти байтам, с него считываются данные по 16 байт и далее над ними выполняются какие-то операции. Над последним блоком данных надо сделать другую операцию, отличную от предыдущих. **Как определить, что блок данных был последним**?
Считывание я реализовал следующим образом:

```py
with open(filename, "rb") as fd:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fd.read(16), b""):
        foo(chunk)
```

На ум приходит "грубое" решение: найти конец потока

```py
fd.seek(0, 2)
end = fd.tell()
fd.seek(0, 0)
```

И далее, после каждого чтения данных, сверять текущую позицию потока с концом.

```py
with open(filename, "rb") as fd:
    fd.seek(0, 2)
    end = fd.tell()
    fd.seek(0, 0)
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fd.read(16), b""):
        if fd.tell() < end:
            foo(chunk)
        else:
            bar(chunk)
```

Есть ли более элегантный способ решить эту задачу?

Comment: А если просто  - чтение под номером size/16 - последнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен насчёт элегантности, но почему бы не читать на один чанк вперёд?

```
with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
    prev_chunk = fp.read(16)
    while True:
        next_chunk = fp.read(16)
        if not next_chunk:
            bar(prev_chunk)
            break
        foo(prev_chunk)
        prev_chunk = next_chunk
```

Или то же самое, но завёрнутое в функцию, чтобы запихнуть неэлегантный код подальше с глаз долой:

```
def chunk_reader(fp, chunk_size):
    prev_chunk = fp.read(chunk_size)
    while True:
        next_chunk = fp.read(chunk_size)
        if not next_chunk:
            yield prev_chunk, True
            break
        yield prev_chunk, False
        prev_chunk = next_chunk

#

with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
    for chunk, is_last in chunk_reader(fp, 16):
        if is_last:
            bar(chunk)
        else:
            foo(chunk)
```

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но почему Вы назвали переменную `fp`? Не первый раз уже вижу, что переменная `fp` является типом `_io.BufferedReader`, стало интересно, почему.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов все так пишут, и я за всеми повторяю) А вообще наверно вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943049

Comment: Интересно) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность загрузить файл в память целиком, можно сделать так:

```py
def readchunks(filename, size=16):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        yield from iter(lambda: file.read(size), b'')
```

```py
*initial, last = readchunks('filename')
```

где `initial` - список всех чанков, кроме последнего, `last` - последний чанк. Если файл изначально пустой, будет выброшено исключение.

Если же файл может быть слишком большим, и/или пустым, стоит реализовать дополнительную обертку для потока, которая будет кроме самого элемента возвращать признак завершения.

```py
import itertools

def marklast(iterable):
    it1, it2 = itertools.tee(iterable)

    for _, el in zip(itertools.islice(it1, 1, None), it2):
        yield el, False

    for el in it2:
        yield el, True
```

```py
for el, islast in marklast(readchunks('filename')):
    if islast:
        print('LAST', el)
    else:
        print(el)
```

Но тут тоже нужно иметь в виду, что при пустом файле цикл не выполнится ни разу, а значит условие `islast` не сработает. Это можно обойти вот так:

```py
for el, islast in marklast(readchunks('filename')):
    if islast:
        print('LAST', el)
        break
    else:
        print(el)
else:
    print('Пустой файл')
```

Если цикл `for` выполнился не вызвав `break`, срабатывает ветка `else`