# Как проще всего выполнить отдельное действие для последней итерации цикла for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:

    for row in f:
        print(row.replace('\n', ''), end=", ")
```

Допустим, после последней строчки я хочу поставить не запятую, а точку. Как решить эту задачу максимально просто?

Comment: [Как определить что блок данных из файла является последним](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965791)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно итерировать до предпоследнего элемента включительно, а после добавить код для последнего:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for row in lines[:-1]:
        print(row.replace('\n', ''), end=", ")

    print(lines[-1].replace('\n', ''), end=".")
```

Или воспользоваться методом `join`, объединив строки:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    print(', '.join(row.replace('\n', '') for row in lines) + ".")
    # Или:
    print(', '.join(row.replace('\n', '') for row in lines), end=".")
```

Или считать индексы:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for i, row in enumerate(lines):
        print(row.replace('\n', ''), end=", " if i < len(lines) - 1 else '.')
```

Comment: Постоянно забываю про существоание enumerate, а это хороший способ

Comment: Все три способа корректно отработают, если в списке 0 строк (0 итераций цикла)?

Answer (score 3):

Конкретно эту задачу можно было бы решить вот так, поэтому оставлю здесь этот ответ

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(*[row.replace('\n', '') for row in f], sep=", ", end=".")
```

Comment: Классное решение с `sep` :)

Comment: @gil9red но оно подходит только если речь идет про print, меня больше интересовало есть ли способ как-то просто задать действие для последней итерации. Ваше первое решение наверное лучше отвечает на этот вопрос)

Comment: Вы теряете первую строку (т.к. забираете ее на первой итерации внешнего цикла). Внешний цикл тут лишний. И еще, для `row.replace('\n', '')` есть специальный метод `str.rstrip`.

Comment: @mkkik По поводу внешнего цикла, это я просто ошибся, забыл его удалить :) До компа доберусь, поправлю. А про rstrip - да, спасибо, это полезный совет

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не считывать все строки в память, можно запоминать предыдущую строку и её выводить с запятой в конце. А после цикла, когда предыдущей станет последняя строка, выведем её с точкой.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: 
    prev = None
    for row in f:
        if prev != None:
            print(prev.replace('\n', ''), end=", ")
        prev = row
    print(prev.replace('\n', ''), end=".")
```

Comment: Полезная штука, если строк дофига)